# Flutter how to access Provider Context in FCM backgroundHandler static method?

Tags: flutter

I have  setup background notifications , Hive (To store Notification Locally Using Adapter Class) and Setup a ChangeNotifier ModelClass to get Updates in UI.

Problem: I want to Add Notification data In Hive With ModelClass to get Notified in UI ,If Application is Not Active.

Now I need to access Provider.of(context) in my backgroundHandler which must be a static method where there is no context.

All I need to do is to perform an action according to the data in the background notification.

[Same As In this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65050563/flutter-how-to-access-provider-ofcontext-in-fcm-backgroundhandler-static-metho)

Comment: you can use `context` in `didChangeDependencies()` in StatefulWidget you can also pass the context in argument from build method when you calling the function

Comment: I want to get Notified When ITEM gets Added In the Hive Box.
Like This: 
await Provider.of<ModelClass>(context, listen: false).addItem(item);

Inside FCM BackgroundMessage Handler.
It's Only Getting Updates On UI ,When I Completly detached the Application and Run Again. Then Only Hive Box is Showing Updates. @AkshayNayka

Comment: @adarshraj did you find any solution?